# My subprogram does not work in C language

Tags: c, xcode, return, partialfunction

I wrote a subprogram in C with Xcode that calculates a partial function but it does not work.

I know there is a a lot wrong with " return " statements but i couldn't find a way to make it better.

I made "return (result * 1 )" and "return(result = result)" for return, took every function between return parentheses like " return(result = pow(x,5) + pow(y,3)); " but none of them worked.

Can you please show me how to make it right and explain why?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double
funmath(int x, int y)
{
    double result;
    
    if( x >= 50 )
        result = pow(x,5) + pow(y,3);
    else if( x >= 40 )
        result = 5 * x + y + 9;
    else if( x >= 0 )
        result = x / 5 + 7 * y;
    else
    
    return(result);
}
```

Comment: You have `return` only in the final `else` branch, not in the other branches. Drop the final `else` keyword so that the return moves outside the if statement.

Comment: Optionally initialize result to something so that it returns something well-defined if none of the ifs are satisfied.

Comment: I am not sure what the result should be when x < 0.  But in general, what you are doing right now is either assign a value to result, but not return it (if x >= 50, 40 or 0), or not assign any value to result and return it (after else, that is, if x < 0).
You should add a line of code after else, "result = ....;". BTW, in C, you don't need brackets after return. return result; will suffice.

Comment: P.S. Teapot's solution is as good as mine, but I'd recommend initializing result, as he/she states in the second comment - I think it's good practice :)

Answer (score 3):

You asked for a solution and an explanation.

## The solution

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double
funmath(int x, int y)
{
    double result = -42; //You can use some other default value instead if you prefer
    
    if( x >= 50 )
        result = pow(x,5) + pow(y,3);
    else if( x >= 40 )
        result = 5 * x + y + 9;
    else if( x >= 0 )
        result = x / 5 + 7 * y;
    
    return(result);
}
```

## Explanation

Your `double` function needs to `return` **something** in any case. Your function has these cases:

- `if (x >= 50)`: you set `result` to some value, but you do not `return` anything
- `else if( x >= 40 )`: you set `result` to some value, but do not `return` anything
- `else if( x >= 0 )`: you set `result` to some value, but do not `return` anything
- `else`: You do not initialize `result`, but you return it

Let's not forget that `else if` means that none of the conditions of the `if` and earlier `else if`s than the current condition was true, but the condition of the current `else if` is true and let's not forget that `else` means that "none of the above is true". Since you had your `return` inside your `else`, in the first three cases you do not `return` anything, hence, you violate the best practices of the language. This is why, the solution is to `return` something, no matter what.

Comment: Re “you violate the rules of the language”: FYI, there is no rule in the C standard that a function with non-`void` return type must always return a value.

Comment: @EricPostpischil excuse me, I have not been working with C in the latest 15 years. Nevertheless, changed the quote to "you violate the best practices of the language". Thanks for the observation!

Comment: The rule is: [If the `}` that terminates a function is reached, and the value of the function call is used by the caller, the behavior is undefined.](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.9.1p12).